# Inheriting from a JSON converter class with schema definition through constructor

Tags: c++, design-patterns, json, pointers

I wanted to convert C++ data structures to JSON with little code. More specifically, I wanted to convert C++ data structures to [nlohmann JSON](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) representation.

**Project context**: The goal is to use this in a somewhat large professional application (~50k code-lines) deployed for years in a **not so** critical product. I'm just trying to explain the importance of the code quality (hard to judge within the project team as well). Permission to share was granted.

I came up with a solution ([full source](https://github.com/ricardocrl/joc)), where "any" user class/struct can inherit from a converter class, **`JsonObject`**:

```cpp
struct Contact : public JsonObject
{
  Contact() : JsonObject({{"name", name},
                          {"phone_number", phone},
                          {"age", age},
                          {"e-mail", email}
                         }) {}
  std::string name;
  std::string phone;
  int age;
  std::optional<std::string> email;
};
```

As you can see, the schema of the JSON is defined in the call to the base `JsonObject` constructor.

`JsonObject` has the following constructor:

```cpp
JsonObject::JsonObject(const std::vector<JsonPair>& pairs, std::mutex* dataMutex)
    : mPairs(pairs)
    , mDataMutex(dataMutex)
{}
```

`mPairs` and `mDataMutex` are the only members of the class. `dataMutex` has default value `nullptr`, for cases where no thread synchronization is required with mutexes. When a `mDataMutex` is valid, read/write accesses to the value, through `mAddress`, are thread safe (see `JsonObject::toJson` and `JsonObject::refreshFromJson` below).

The construction of `JsonObject` is designed to not require any arguments passed from the concrete user object, as you can see in the example above. This design, however, makes it possible to implement concrete constructors that end up not calling the `JsonObject` base class constructor properly. In the worst case, converting to and from JSON, for badly constructed objects, would yield an empty JSON object or a dummy parsing from a provided JSON. I probably never considered this, because I am quite familiar with how it works.

**`JsonPair`** is a class that associates a JSON key, implemented with a `std::string`, and a C++ reference to a value, of a template type T. However, `JsonPair` is not a class template; its constructors are templated:

```cpp
template<typename T>
JsonPair(const std::string& name, T& value)
    : mIsOptional(false)
    , mAddress(static_cast<void*>(&value))
    , mName(name)
    , mToJsonFunction(templateToJson<T>)
    , mIsJsonValidFunction(templateIsJsonValid<T>)
    , mHasValueFunction([](const void*) { return true; })
    , mFromJsonFunction(templateFromJson<T>)
{}
```

A second constructor exists that takes a `std::optional<T>& value` instead of a `T& value`:

```cpp
template<typename T>
JsonPair(const std::string& name, std::optional<T>& value)
    : mIsOptional(true)
    , mAddress(static_cast<void*>(&value))
    , mName(name)
    , mToJsonFunction(templateOptionalToJson<T>)
    , mIsJsonValidFunction(templateIsJsonValid<T>)
    , mHasValueFunction(
      [](const void* address) { return static_cast<const std::optional<T>*>(address)->has_value(); })
    , mFromJsonFunction(templateOptionalFromJson<T>)
{}
```

By having template constructors, the actual `JsonPair` type is still unique, allowing to have a `std::vector<JsonPair>`, passed in `JsonObject` constructor. This vector contains all key-value pairs the user wants to see in the JSON object representation.

The constructor templates are there to allow initializing `std::function` members with template functions for the conversions to/from JSON of different types. For example:

```cpp
template<typename T>
nlohmann::json::object_t::value_type templateToJson(const std::string& name, const void* value)
{
    return {name, *static_cast<const T*>(value)};
}

template<typename T>
bool templateFromJson(const nlohmann::json& jsonConfig, const std::string& name, void* value)
{
    jsonConfig[name].get_to<T>(*static_cast<T*>(value));
    return true;
}
```

For `std::optional<T>` types, the following counterpart functions are used, via constructor `JsonPair(const std::string& name, std::optional<T>& value)`:

```cpp
template<typename T>
nlohmann::json::object_t::value_type templateOptionalToJson(const std::string& name, const void* optional)
{
    const std::optional<T>& optionalType = *static_cast<const std::optional<T>*>(optional);
    return templateToJson<T>(name, &optionalType.value());
}

template<typename T>
bool templateOptionalFromJson(const nlohmann::json& jsonConfig, const std::string& name, void* optional)
{
    std::optional<T>& optionalType = *static_cast<std::optional<T>*>(optional);
    optionalType                   = T();
    if (jsonConfig[name].is_null())
    {
        optionalType = std::nullopt;
        return true;
    }
    return templateFromJson<T>(jsonConfig, name, &optionalType.value());
}
```

The signatures above do not depend on type T. Therefore these functions can be assigned to the internal `std::function` members. `JsonPair` takes the address of the value reference and stores it in member `void* mAddress`.

---

Now, to get a better picture of the complete `JsonObject` implementation, let's now look at the public API implementation of:

- `JsonObject::toJson` and `JsonObject::refreshFromJson`
- `JsonPair::toJson` and `JsonPair::refreshFromJson`

**JsonObject conversion methods**

Note: remember each element of `mPair` is a `JsonPair`.

```cpp
#define LOCK_SCOPE() \
    auto lk = (mDataMutex == nullptr) ? std::unique_lock<std::mutex>() : std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(*mDataMutex);

nlohmann::json JsonObject::toJson() const {
    auto jsonConfig = nlohmann::json::object();

    LOCK_SCOPE();
    for (const auto& p : mPairs) {
        if (p.hasValue()) {
            jsonConfig += p.toJson();
        }
    }
    return jsonConfig;
}

bool JsonObject::refreshFromJson(const nlohmann::json& jsonConfig) {
    if (jsonConfig.empty()) {
        return false;
    }
    auto success = true;

    LOCK_SCOPE();
    for (auto& p : mPairs) {
        if (!p.refreshFromJson(jsonConfig)) {
            success = false;
        }
    }
    return success;
}
```

**JsonPair conversion methods**

```cpp
nlohmann::json::object_t::value_type toJson() const {
    return mToJsonFunction(mName, mAddress);
}

bool refreshFromJson(const nlohmann::json& jsonConfig) {
    bool isValid = true;
    std::string errorMsg;

    const bool explicitNullOpt = mIsOptional && jsonConfig.contains(mName) && jsonConfig[mName].is_null();
    if (explicitNullOpt) {
        // It is valid
    } else {
        errorMsg = mIsJsonValidFunction(jsonConfig, mName);
        isValid  = errorMsg.empty();
    }
 
    if (!isValid) {
        if (mIsOptional) {
            std::cout << "Optional field: '" << mName << "': " << errorMsg << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Mandatory field: '" << mName << "': " << errorMsg << std::endl;
        }
    } else {
        isValid = mFromJsonFunction(jsonConfig, mName, mAddress);
    }
    return isValid || mIsOptional;
}
```

This JSON conversion approach could probably be more efficient and clean, using directly `nlohmann::adl_serializer`. The only reason was that I did not realize this existed until quite late, when `JsonObject` was getting traction. However, I started using a bit of it inside the implementations of `templateToJson` and `templateFromJson`.

Inclusively, I added support for nested `JsonObject` objects, and automatic support for std::vector as a value in `JsonPair, representing a JSON array, by simply providing ADL implementations:

```cpp
void to_json(nlohmann::json& j, const JsonObject& joc)
{
    j = joc.toJson();
}

void from_json(const nlohmann::json& j, JsonObject& joc)
{
    joc.refreshFromJson(j);
}
```

---

Here is an example of converting to JSON:

```cpp
Contact mary;
mary.name    = "Mary";
mary.age     = 52;
mary.phone   = "+85930461920";
std::cout << mary.toJson().dump(2) << std::endl;
```

---

In order to be able to copy `JsonObject` objects, I had to play a trick with the copy of `std::vector<JsonPair> mPairs`. While copying this member, the addresses stored refer to the original object. So, to "fix" the address of the copied object, I implemented the copy constructor like this:

```cpp
JsonObject::JsonObject(const JsonObject& other)
    : mPairs(other.mPairs) {
    updateAddresses(other);
}

void JsonObject::updateAddresses(const JsonObject& origin) {
    auto ptrInt      = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(static_cast<JsonObject*>(this));
    auto otherPtrInt = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(static_cast<const JsonObject*>(&origin));
    std::uintptr_t diff;
    if (ptrInt > otherPtrInt) {
        diff = ptrInt - otherPtrInt;
    } else {
        diff = otherPtrInt - ptrInt;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < mPairs.size(); ++i) {
        if (ptrInt > otherPtrInt) {
            mPairs[i].setAddress(
                reinterpret_cast<void*>(reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(origin.mPairs[i].getMutableAddress()) + diff));
        } else {
            mPairs[i].setAddress(
                reinterpret_cast<void*>(reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(origin.mPairs[i].getMutableAddress()) - diff));
        }
    }
}
```

In brief, after copying `mPairs`, `updateAddresses()` is called to adjust the memory addresses copied to `mPairs`, given the memory offset between the source and destination `JsonObject`.

---

**The review part**

Some design concerns that I would like to get feedback on:

- Consider the coupling that exists between `JsonObject` (the base class) and the user derived class, where **member addresses** are passed to the constructor of `JsonObject`. I believe this is only possible, and guaranteed to work, because the compiler knows the derived class layout when passing the member addresses to `JsonObject` constructor.
- Consider what happens in the `JsonObject` copy-constructor.
- Consider how the user can pass a `std::mutex*` to delegate the access protection to `JsonObject`.

---

I confess I'm not particularly proud of this implementation.
But I'm proud of the ease of using it, and it does what I wanted. But some colleagues are less proud than me. :-)

My main questions are:

1. Do you foresee negative consequences out of this design?
2. Having in mind that the solution is intentionally designed as is, could this be an acceptable exotic solution?

Comment: Is there a reason you have avoided the "standard" approach described in the nlohmann-json readme? (i.e. providing `from_json` and `to_json` functions, or specializing `nlohmann::adl_serializer`?

Comment: @user673679, I didn't realize `nlohmann::adl_serializer` existed until late (`JsonObject` was already getting traction). I do use it though, for converting a `JsonObject` to `nlohmann::json`, allowing nested `JsonObjects`. If I was to start over, I wouldn't probably find this implementation worth the effort/risk. However, I think this approach has a few different characteristics (good or bad) compared to `nlohmann::adl_serializer`. I'm going to find some time to improve the question and explain this non-adl_serializer choice.